# Can ruby's string method .include? be used with a bang operator?

Tags: ruby

I want to check if a string does not include something.

```
string = "this is a sentence about walking"
if string.!include?"running"
   puts string
end
```

Comment: In most languages, that would be written roughly as `!string.include?"running"`. Does that not work? I don't know Ruby.

Comment: What about "this is a sentence about [underrunning](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/underrunning)"?

Comment: The code you posted is syntactically valid, you just need to implement the methods you are calling. Whether it is semantically what you want is another question, there isn't enough information in your question to determine that.

Answer (score 3):

Try using regex'es:

```
string = "this is a sentence about walking"
if string.match(/running/)
  puts string
else
  puts "no match present"
end
```

and as you are trying to do in your code just shift the bang sign before the string it will work fine as:

```
string = "this is a sentence about walking"
puts string if !string.include?"running"
```

for more readability use

```
puts string unless string.include?"running"
```

Comment: edited, ruby doesn't use colons like `if:` or `unless:`

Answer (score 3):

you were on the right path just have to correct your syntax

```
string = "this is a sentence about walking"

if !string.include?("running")
   puts string
end
```

Make use of ruby not `!` operator

which would negate the output

So if `string.include?("running")` returning `false` i.e comparison string not present in given string then,

`!string.include?("running")` will return `true`

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa, This is the best answer as I was not looking for regex

Comment: All credits go to Nimish, I have just corrected typos. If you find this answer useful, you have to mark it as the correct one by selecting a green checkmark on the left.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thnx for recognizing it :)

Answer (score 2):

`exclude?` does not work for Strings in ruby.

You can use `unless` with `include?`, see the snippet bellow:

```
string = "this is a sentence about walking"
puts string unless string.include? 'running'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `exclude?` exactly for your use case.

```
require 'active_support/all'
string = "this is a sentence about walking"
puts string if string.exclude? "running"
```

You can do this is Rails.

Comment: This is a Rails thing, but you can get it in a plain Ruby project by including ActiveSupport

Comment: @maxpleaner oops!